# App to put a circle around the mouse pointer

Tags: osx, macos, apple

In some videos, I have seen a circle or a ring around the mouse pointer but I am not able to find any options in my mac to do so.

Is there a way in mac to do this or do I need an app for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several apps to do this.

[Presentify](https://presentify.compzets.com), [Mouse Locator](http://www.2point5fish.com), [Mousepose'](https://boinx.com/mousepose/), and [Cursor Pro](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/cursor-pro/id1447043133?mt=12). All 4 of these apps will do what I want. I would test drive each one and select the one you like best.

Comment: Thanks for the names. Do you have a preference among these? I am not much of a tech guy myself.

Comment: Presentify does a lot of things and is half the price.

Comment: Thanks, jmh. I actually saw all of them and went with Presentify and I couldn't be happier. I am sure I couldn't have found this on the app store by myself. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly also use this library [coxmi/chrome-circle-cursor](https://github.com/coxmi/chrome-circle-cursor) which also comes as a chrome plugin in [chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/circle-cursor/ilelbekedacppdghaclcoolmmdogpbbh?hl=en-GB)